# CSS - Transition width broken when setting a fixed (or absolute) position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element that acts as a `border-bottom` on my header. When the user scrolls down, this border should reach 100% width.

I've set up a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0f7o8q1/8/) with this behaviour.

Now, I also need my header to be fixed at the top when the user scrolls down. So I've added a `position: fixed` property.

But [that breaks my transition](http://jsfiddle.net/o0f7o8q1/7/) on firefox 33. It still works on Chrome though.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: have you tried with -moz in css for firefox

Comment: Yes I did. Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/o0f7o8q1/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625289) where transitions don't properly animate when changing the `position` attribute. It appears to be scheduled for Fx 34.

In an [example](http://www.nicolas-hoffmann.net/bordel/divers/bug-transition-firefox/index.html), referenced from that bug, note that `header2` starts as `position: fixed`, so its width animates as expected.

I'd think your options are to allow the bug for Firefox <=33, or animate using jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: Looks like you're right. Fortunately I'm not in a hurry so I'll leave it as is and wait for the update. Thanks !